# Passing a web.config appsetting to an html page?

Tags: azure, deployment, typescript, single-page-application, appsettings

I'm trying to accomplish this "task" so and I believe I need a bit of "outside the box" thinking on it.

I have an MVC website coupled with a few settings in the web.config. I have an html page (AppCompose.html) (not an MVC, nor aspx page) and unfortunately this must remain an html page. This website very much behaves like an SPA (single page application) where we interact with the user (in the Office add-in world). We're using Typescript in the code. Next we're deploying to Azure (ie there is a deployment process which translates a Parameters.xml to a SetParameters.xml to update the web.config upon deployment to Azure). We also have a downstream dependency which is going to take our transpiled JS and html files and use them in their own app and they don't have a web server.

I would like to figure out a way to "pass" app setting values from the web.config to the html page?

Challenges?

- I would like to avoid calling a web service as the dependent team doesn't have a web server to run in
- I need to be "Azure deployment friendly" as we're building in a mature process (dev, qa and prod deployment environments)
- I need to be able to read the parameters values in the Typescript\Javascript at runtime on the clients

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.